# Oil Pastel Shader

Tags: materials, shaders, procedural

I'm wondering how you could create a procedural oil pastel shader.

[image]

Comment: Please add a bit more details to your question. What you want to achieve with this shader? Make stylized render? Paint with it? Add some reference images of what you finally want to achieve with it.